# Is Lora maximum transmission 1 km in real?

Tags: arduino, communication, wireless, lora

I'm new to wireless communication and Lora.
I'm using Lora Ra-02 and Arduino UNO and small 800 Mhz antenna.
I'm using Arduino website library.

How can I increase that range?  What do I need to do to get that 2-3 km urban range?

Does it need line of sight even in short distance communication?

What points should I focus on to have maximum range?

Comment: The range depends on a lot of factors, type of antenna, weather, terrain, etc.

Comment: Line of sight will certainly make life easier.

Comment: I've measured 1.2 km with bluetooth. I would jump up and down of joy if I could get even one tenth of that inside an office building...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claimed range for low-cost wireless gadgets often represents a triumph of marketing over engineering. The range may be achievable "in free space" with a clear line sight between two units, but not in the real world with structures, vegetation, interference, and the curvature of the earth intruding.

Since the transmit power and receiver sensitivity of the modules are fixed, and assuming you've already chosen the lowest data rate protocol, your best best is to use better antennas, and antenna siting, on one or both ends. Instead of a short piece of wire protruding from the device, use coaxial cable to connect an antenna that is outside, and mounted higher above the ground if possible. If your devices are at fixed locations, you can even use directional antennas. With 6 - 10 dB of antenna directional gain, you can extend the range by the factor or 2 to 3 that you are seeking. Search for "800 MHz yagi antenna" and you'll find several.
[image: Here is just one example]

Comment: Thanks for your useful help and complete explanation.
This is my antenna 
https://www.amazon.in/INVENTO-antenna-Quad-Band-Female-Connector/dp/B08KGZGD55/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=ufl+antenna&qid=1603108979&sr=8-3
And I was thinking about connecting a telescopic or yagi antenna to Lora 
but I can't find the connector
Is there a way to connect this kind of antennas to Lora with Ipex connector?
and is there any difference in details if I work with a Lora 433Mhz !?

Comment: You can use the short cables from your existing antennas, which look like they have a U.fl connector for the radio end, and a female SMA connector on the other end. Find out what connectors your directional antennas have -- maybe BNC or type N -- and buy coaxial cables of the needed length which SMA male on one end, and a mating connector for the antenna on the other.   Re 433 MHz: that's about twice the wavelength of 800 MHz, and as a rule of thumb, that will double the range, assuming you use antennas of the same gain at both frequencies.

Comment: actually acquiring this tool is a bit hard in my city but I'll go through it
I appreciate your help Mr. Leavitt